# Scroll bug in visual studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-designer

So the GroupBox i am trying to place is larger than the screen real state of the designer in visual studio.

Hence i scroll to make room however after scrolling whenever i try to re-size the groupbox the designer immediately scrolls back to the center of the control making it immpossible for me to re-size the control.

Is this some sort of bug or am i doing something wrong it was working fine previously and suddenly i have this problem now tried closing and reopening VS but the problem is still there.

I Should probably add that i am using telerik's radforms.

Comment: Have you tried selecting the group box and using the Shift/Arrow keys?

Comment: @rrirower Yup as soon as i press Shift + Arrow Key to re-size the control the designer immediately scrolls back to the center of the control. Damn this is making resizing control immpossible